# Abnormally large figure's bottom margin when it's the first item on the page

Tags: floats, margins

Regardless of what comes before or after a figure (in the screenshots below I've added one word paragraphs to simplify the page layout calculation), I end up with huge bottom margins *when the figure is the very first item on the page*:

```
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, center]{images/07/ondemand.png}
\caption{On-demand script from a Server\label{fig:ondemand}}
\end{figure}

Whatever (ad lib.)
```

[image: Wrong bottom spacing when the image is the first item on the page]

As soon as I add one text line before it, the correct space is restored:

```
Whatever

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=1\textwidth, center]{images/07/ondemand.png}
\caption{On-demand script from a Server\label{fig:ondemand}}
\end{figure}

Whatever (ad lib.)
```

[image: Proper bottom spacing when the image is not the first item on the page]

It's a bit hard for me to provide a MWE; I'm using a `scrbook` class, I've checked my stylings and the only parts related to figures are as follows:

```
\creflabelformat{figure}{(#2#1)#3}
\addto\captionsenglish{\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.}}
\usepackage{float}
\floatplacement{figure}{h}
\setlength{\textfloatsep}{20mm plus 2mm minus 4mm}
\captionsetup[figure]{
  position=bottom,
  skip=3mm,
  labelfont={bf,sf,color=caption-label-color},
  textfont={blah,color=caption-text-color},
  singlelinecheck=false,
  justification=centering,
  labelformat=parens,
  labelsep=enskip
}
```

I don't have any other particular issue with them; I understand that the engine does its best to place items on the page, and I've nothing to complain about the actual position of the figure, it's where it is supposed to be.

The only problem is that huge bottom margin (approx 2.5x) when the page starts with a figure. I've tried adding all sorts of different paragraphs *after it*, but I constantly get an abnormally large margin.

Does this ring any bell?
Thank you very much in advance

Comment: Well, it is also very hard to help you since we actually don't know, what you doing. For start try to replace placement option `[h]` with `[htbp]` and see if any changes in your document happens.

Comment: Try using \raggedbottom or adding \vspace*{\fill} at the bottom of the page.  I'm working on the theory that the next page starts with a large box and the only glue on this page is around the figure.  And start using [ht] instead of [h].  It only matters at the bottom of the page.

Comment: it should be easy for you to supply a test document. start from a copy of your document, use example-image as the test image and then delete everything apart from the text and packages needed to show a bad page. that said most likely raggefbotom is what you are looking for